# SFMC Content Builder API Calls

Tags: api, rest, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I need to search this particular word "Home Centre" in all the emails.

```
Tried this query
POST: https://XXXXXXXX.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/query
Body:
```

{

"query": {
"property": "content",
"simpleOperator": "mustcontain",
"value": "Home Centre"
},
"fields": [
"id",
"name"
]
}

The JSON response doesn't contain all the email names wondering if there is any limit in the response returned.
This is the starting of the response

```
{
    "count": 322,
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "links": {},
```

Does this mean there is only 1 page?

Comment: It means there are 7 pages -- 322/50 rounded up.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSpriggs also is there a way to find out when was the last date these emails were sent?

Comment: Not with pulling Content Builder assets, no.